# How can I update aspnet-scaffolding cshtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC 5 controller with views,using entity framework and create, delete, details, edit, index cshtml pages occurs automatically. When I change the model classes and update the database CSHTML pages don't change. I am manually deleting view pages and recreating them with scaffolding. When I do these things my HTML designs are deleted.

How can I update aspnet-scaffolding cshtml pages automatically?

**Note:** I am using layout pages but they aren't solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When i do these things my html desings are deleted. "

Here is the root of the issue.  If I understand you correctly you are:

1. Using scaffolding to generate Views.
2. Modifying the CSHTML of those views to customize the View.

Your hope is that after you modify the database, the scaffolding will update the views.  However, when it generates the new CSHTML Views, how does it know how to combine the changes with your customizations?  It doesn't.  **It can't know how to generate a completely new view and somehow integrate your customizations.**

This is pretty much the same with any scenario that involves code generation.  You have to make a choice.  If you want to preserve your edits, you can no longer use the scaffolding to generate new views after editing.  If you want to benefit from scaffolding after database updates, then you should never edit the CSHTML with the intention of customizing it.

I used scaffolding a long time ago only as a learning tool, to see how things like lists were handled.  For probably 2 years I have never used scaffolding, and it is generally slow for larger projects, so I just always create an empty CSHTML or copy an existing one that is close to the approach I will take with the new one.

I would instead focus on other techniques that will help make creating CSHTML easier.

- Using partial Views appropriately to pull reusable UI elements out.
- Use Custom Object Templates to customize the results of things like DisplayFor and EditorFor.(I personally don't do this but I've seen others use it effectively)
- Implemented helpers to take in parameters and produce HTML that fits the patterns you follow.  Since I use bootstrap I created my own `Html.LabelForBootstrap` helper for example, that outputs HTML formatted for use with bootstrap with bootstrap classes.
- Effective use of Layout pages and sections.

Eventually you will begin to see that the scaffolding isn't at all appropriate in many cases.  E.g. the UI for relating one entity to another, the fact that it shows all columns when many aren't appropriate for display, etc.

You might be interested in Dynamic Data.  It is more convention oriented in that it determines UI from database structure, but you provide customization conventions.  Overall it's not really different conceptually from using MVC with Custom Object Templates:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee845452(v=vs.100).aspx

Dynamic Data isn't mainstream, and skills you learn from using it probably aren't very marketable.  It is probably only appropriate for administrative interfaces where user experience isn't a primary concern.  Once you learn MVC really well you can pretty quickly spit out basic UI for new entities, so I don't recommend Dynamic Data.

It is possible to **modify the default scaffolding templates**.  So if you wanted to, you could customize the template and have it generate your views.  **You will quickly run into the same issue** however, as you will encounter a scenario where your generic template doesn't satisfy and you need to customize the output View CSHTML, but now you can no longer regenerate the View so the scaffolding template has limited usefulness:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx